# passwd fails with "Authentication token manipulation error" for NIS

Tags: centos, nis

On centos 7 I have the following pam config:

```
cat /etc/pam.d/passwd      
#%PAM-1.0
auth       include  system-auth
account    include  system-auth
password   substack system-auth
-password   optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so use_authtok
password   substack postlogin
```

and

```
cat /etc/pam.d/system-auth 
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so try_first_pass nullok
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so try_first_pass use_authtok nullok sha512 shadow nis
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
account     required      pam_slurm.so
```

but when I run "passwd" as a user it asks me for the current passwd, new password and retype and then fails with

```
passwd
Changing password for user test.
Changing password for test.
(current) UNIX password: 
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

And ideas how to fix or debug this?

Note: yppasswd works fine, just passwd fails

Update: I tried the same config with a different server and there it works. So I figure the problem is server side, not client. Still no idea how debug this properly.

Comment: This can be caused by missing entries in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`. Manually add your user to `/etc/passwd` if its not there, and add a line for your user in `/etc/shadow` like `test::17807:0:99999:7:::`. This allows login as `test` without a password so you can change `test`s password.

Comment: @expz If those were missing then yppasswd wouldn't work.

Comment: I had a similar problem on my centos 7 lab machine. According to [this article](https://www.hivelocity.net/kb/how-to-resolve-passwd-authentication-token-manipulation-error-for-cpanel/), the issue occurs when `/usr/bin/passwd` has incorrect permissions and running `chmod 4511 /usr/bin/passwd` should fix the issue. It woked for me. YMMV.